# coalesced and predictive touch in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, touch

I have a huge project (an App) in Objective C and I want to make a serious transition to iOS 9. There is a lot of drawing in the app and I want to use predictive and coalesced touch. As described in http://flexmonkey.blogspot.de/2015/09/advanced-touch-handling-in-ios9.html
 The code there looks like

```
if let coalescedTouches = event.coalescedTouchesForTouch(touch)
    {
        print("coalescedTouches:", coalescedTouches.count)

        for coalescedTouch in coalescedTouches
        {
            let locationInView = coalescedTouch.locationInView(view)

            coalescedDrawPath.addLineToPoint(locationInView)
            coalescedDrawPath.appendPath(UIBezierPath.createCircleAtPoint(locationInView, radius: 2))
            coalescedDrawPath.moveToPoint(locationInView)
        }

        coalescedDrawLayer.path = coalescedDrawPath.CGPath
    }
```

However this is Swift. Is there any direct way to use these features also in objective C. I did find nothing on the web.

Comment: You found nothing on the web about using swift to augment an obj-c project?

Comment: Why would the OP want to augment their obj-c project with swift, when it's trivial to write the code in obj-c? This is a very reasonable question, so I don't understand why it has been downvoted. If you look at Apple's website, there is only example code for swift, none for obj-c.

Answer (score 1):

That block of code in objective c is something like:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UIBezierPath *coalescedPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    [coalescedPath moveToPoint:CGPointZero];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([event coalescedTouchesForTouch:touch]) {
        NSArray *coalescedTouches = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [event coalescedTouchesForTouch:touch]];
        NSLog(@"Coalesced Touches: %lu",(unsigned long)[coalescedTouches count]);
        for (UITouch*coalescedTouch in coalescedTouches) {
            CGPoint locationInView = [coalescedTouch locationInView:self.view];
            [coalescedPath addLineToPoint:locationInView];
            [coalescedPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(locationInView.x-2.0, locationInView.y-2.0, 4.0, 4.0)]];
            [coalescedPath moveToPoint:locationInView];
        }
        [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
        [coalescedPath stroke];

    }
}
```

For the moment of all of Apple's API is being written in both Objective C and Swift. Look at UITouch and UIEvent reference guides on how to implement predictive and coalesced touch API.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. I simply did not find it  (looked in the wrong class)